# While loop is printing two times output

Tags: php, mysql

In my code, while loop is printing two times output. Here is my PHP code:

```
if($con) 
{
    echo '<h1>Connected to MySQL</h1>';
    $sql = 'select age, salary from emp';
    mysql_select_db('toor');
    $retval = mysql_query($sql, $con);

    if(!$retval)
        die('could not get data'.mysql_error());

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($retval, MYSQL_NUM))
    {
        echo "age:{$row[0]}<br>"."sal:{$row[1]}<br>";
    }
}
```

Comment: Consider stop using mysql_* functions as this extension is not supported any more and removed from the latest PHP versions. Using it may result in security breach in your product.

Answer (score -1):

Replace
`$row = mysql_fetch_array($retval, MYSQL_NUM)`
  with
`$row = mysql_fetch_array($retval)`

and remove `$con` from `mysql_query()`

Comment: Or don't use `mysql_` because it's deprecated.